# Rails 末尾に表示されるログの表示時間の意味

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Railsにアクセスすると表示されるおなじみの下記出内容について自分の解釈が正しいのかと思いましたので質問させていただきます。

`Completed 200 OK in 111ms (Views: 37.9ms | ActiveRecord: 2.8ms)`

普段ログを見るときは`ActiveRecord`の所はDBとのやりとりでかかった時間と認識していますが
それ以外の`111ms`と`Views`の時間がよく分かっていません。
`Views`はRailsがhtmlやcss、jsonを出力するのにかかった時間、`111ms`はリクエストを受けてから返すまでの合計時間という認識であっていますでしょうか？
`111ms`から`Views`の時間と`ActiveRecord`の時間を引くことでその他の部分、つまりロジックにかかった時間が分かるということでしょうか？

Railsの処理時間の測定方法は検索して沢山見つかりましたが、標準のログ出力についての説明が見つかりませんでしたので質問しました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

111msがリクエストの処理全体にかかった時間、そのうちViewsに37.9ms、AR (データベース周り) に2.8msで、ここに付いては合っています。

それ以外の部分は、コントローラの処理に加えて、直接・間接的に呼び出される処理 (モデル、I/O、その他APIなどのリクエスト) などを全て含めた数字ですので、単純にロジックのみの時間というわけではありません。